# EventBus implementation using Coroutines and LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata

I need to broadcast events from different places within my app, and I need these events to be listened by different ViewModels. What I did is that I created a "custom" implementation of EventBus using Kotlin Coroutines, `Channel` more specifically. The implementation looks like this:

```
interface FlowEventBus {

    sealed class MessageEvent {
        data class MessageA(
            val someData: Int
        ) : MessageEvent()
        data class MessageB(
            val someOtherData: String
        ) : MessageEvent()
        object MessageC : MessageEvent()
    }

    suspend fun postMessage(messageEvent: MessageEvent)
    fun flowMessage(): Flow<MessageEvent>
}

class FlowEventBusImpl() : FlowEventBus {
    private val channel = Channel<FlowEventBus.MessageEvent>()

    override suspend fun postMessage(messageEvent: FlowEventBus.MessageEvent) {
        channel.send(messageEvent)
    }

    override fun flowMessage(): Flow<FlowEventBus.MessageEvent> {
        return channel.receiveAsFlow()
    }
}
```

Then in my ViewModels I use it like this

```
@HiltViewModel
class SomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val flowEventBus: FlowEventBus
) : ViewModel() {
    
    val message = flowEventBus.flowMessage().asLiveData()
    // ...
```

The idea is that whatever `Activity` or `Fragment` is using this ViewModel, they can observe the `message` property and react to the "EventBus" events.

**What's the problem?**

Some of these events are unreliable. For example, let's say `ActivityA` is observing `messages` and it prompts a `Snackbar` every time we get a `MessageC` event. If the `FlowEventBus` broadcasts a `MessageC` event *twice* we'd only see the `Snackbar` pop once.
I'm not very savvy about Kotlin Coroutines yet, what I think might be happening is the classing `SingleLiveEvent` scenario. My guess is that the `asLiveData()` extension turns the `Flow` into a `MutableLiveData` and if we set the same value twice, it will just ignore it. But I'm not sure how to introduce `SingleLiveEvent` here.

Any feedback is welcome,
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite it is not a **direct** answer to your question... But

Why do you need the conversion from flow to live data? Just subscribe to flow on ui layer and populate the flow with necessary livedata features. Believe me, this will make your life much more easier.

I offer to do it by using
`implementation androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:x.y.z` and `SharedFlow`

In **fragment**:

```
with(viewModel) {
    eventsFlow.collectWhenStarted(viewLifecycleOwner, ::processEvents)
}
```

`collectWhenStarted` is a utility method which i offer to simplify subscribing a bit. It utilises using of `launchWhenStarted` method from the library:

```
inline fun <T> Flow<T>.collectWhenStarted(
    lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner,
    crossinline action: suspend (T) -> Unit
): Job = lifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
    collectLatest {
        action.invoke(it)
    }
}
```

You can create similar utilities for other lifecycle events

To substitute a `LiveData` feature of persisting the data between configuration changes, background/foreground changes just convert a regular flow from domain layer to `SharedFlow` with replay.
In a **view model**:

```
val eventsFlow: Flow<DataClass> = flowEventBus
    .flowMessage()
    .shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Lazily, 1)
```

In case you are not `distinct` the emitted elements your EventBus shouldn't exclude any item you passed there

Check this [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-from-livedata-to-kotlins-flow-379292f419fb), the approach described there is close to what i suggest

Comment: Thanks for the **very** detailed answer!  To answer your first question, all my ViewModels they expose LiveData properties, so I guess I wanted to keep it consistent, but I'll definitely try this that you shared here. I'm not very saavy about `SharedFlow` but I guess it is as good as time as any to start using it!